# Codeigniter function not working when trying to validate user information with database

Tags: codeigniter, validation, model

I am creating a login system and for some reason it redirects back to the login page even after i have put in the correct email and password. The called model function doesnt seem to work. Here is my code:

Controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Login extends CI_Controller {



        function validation()
        {

            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim');
             $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5');



            if ($this->form_validation->run()){

                redirect('login/valid_credentials'); 

            }else{

              $this->load->view('login_form');
              //return false;    
            }

        }




        function valid_credentials(){

           $this->load->model('login_model');
            // oh i see

             if ($this->login_model->match_login()){
                //return true;
                 $data = array(
                    'id'=>$q['id'], 

                    'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
                  'is_logged_in'=> 1);
                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                $this->load->view('dashboard_view', $data);

           }else{
                 $this->load->view('login_form');


            }

       }
```

Model:

```
class Login_model extends CI_Model{

    public function match_login(){

        $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'));
        $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
        $q = $this->db->get('user');

        if($q->num_rows()== 1){

          return true;

        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
<?php

echo "<h1 class ='col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-5'>SIGN IN</h1>";


echo form_open('login/validation', $grid);


echo "<h2>Client</h2>";

"<h3>Please Login</h3>";

echo validation_errors();

echo "<p> Email: </br>";
echo form_input ('email');
echo "</p>";


echo "<p> Password: </br>";
echo form_password ('password');
echo "</p>";




echo "<p>";
echo form_submit ('submit', 'Signin');
 echo "</p>";

echo form_close();

?>
```

For some reason, it is not working, Am not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Need to **validate form in one function** and **check login in another function**. use one function for do all.

**Changes**

1. Controller code change and optimized
2. Model code changed

**Some References**

1. [CodeIgniter Form Validation in  **FromGet.com**](https://www.formget.com/form-validation-using-codeigniter/) (Personally Recommend this site )
2. [Form Validation in **Codeigniter.com**](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html)

---

Try this

**Controller**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Login extends CI_Controller {     

        function validation()
        {

            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5');


            if ($this->form_validation->run()  == FALSE )
            {
                $this->load->view('login_form');
                //return false; 
            }
            else{

                $this->load->model('login_model');

                $email = $this->input->post('email');
                $password = $this->input->post('password');

                $result = $this->login_model->match_login($email, $password);

                if ($result ==false) {
                    echo "Invalid Cardinals";
                 } 
                 else 
                 {
                    $session = array(
                      'id'=>$result[0]['id'], 
                      'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
                      'is_logged_in'=> 1
                    );
                    if (!$this->session->set_userdata($session)) {

                        $data['modelData'] = $result;
                        $data['sessionData'] = $session;

                        $this->load->view('dashboard_view', $data);
                    }
                     else {
                        echo "Error in session";.
                    }                          
                }   
            }            
        }
```

**Model**

```
class Login_model extends CI_Model{

    public function match_login($email, $password){

        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        $this->db->where('password', md5($password));
        $query = $this->db->get('user');

        $result = $query->result_array();

        if (empty($result)) 
        {
            return false;
        } 
        else 
        {
            return $result;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but it returned false giving "invalid cardinals" I manually put in an email and  md5 password into the db. it still gave invalid cardinals. Is it possible the md5 generate different md5 hash for the same password?

Comment: remove md5 and add simple password to bd. Like 123456 and check without MD5

Comment: I took the md5 out and it still returns false giving "invalid cardinals".

Comment: `$this->db->where('password', md5($password));` in model alse need to remove

Comment: that was the first md5 i removed. it is now: $this->db-> where('password', $password);

Comment: that was the first md5 i removed. it is now: $this->db-> where('password', $password);

Comment: in model comment all the code and `echo` these and post data `$email`, `$password`

Comment: I commented the model and echoed the email and password. it os generating a hash password

Comment: I commented the model and echoed the email and password. it is generating a hash password

Comment: Show me output of that

Comment: this is the output ; happy@happy.coma102c4a959dfe7efdd3a4e112bee0407

Comment: remove MD5 on here too `$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5');`

Comment: I did that and the password comes up: happy@happy.comloves

Comment: i made the model active again and it returned true. Do you know why it did not go through with md5  password?

Comment: think password is wrong. add MD5 password afer creating new user via form. then its fine

Comment: i took out the md5 in the model as it was hashing the hashed password. Thank you for your help